# Is there a way to click on `Site Information` button in the address bar from Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, chromium, ui-automation

I'm trying to compile a chromium build from scratch and use it with Puppeteer as I want to extract some data from webpage which is available only in memory. I managed to build Chromium using modified source and boot it up with Puppeteer. I implemented this so that the data is written to `stdout` when I click the `Site Information` button in the address bar. But using Puppeteer I can't find a way to click on the `Site Information` button. Is it possible to do so that I can automate the whole process ?

Edit: I'm not looking for the information from Site Information Button. All I want is to emulate the click on that button so that I can print some data that is stored in memory in the C++ chromium source. I find the data by inspecting source code, but had no way to take it outside.